# Can I remove the countdown when installing extensions in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, extension

When installing an extension in Firefox, the confirmation dialog makes you wait 5 seconds before you can install the extension. I find it annoying and unnecessary, is there a way to shorten or remove the countdown so I can install extensions without waiting?

[image]

Comment: a quick google search turned up nothing... and we really don't know why it is there... but it looks like it is going to get removed in Firefox 4 eventually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found this:

You can easily disable the installation wait by a simple ***"about:config"*** modification.

**1.** Type **about:config** into the Firefox address bar and hit enter.

**2.** Click on **"I'll be careful, I promise!"** button.
[image]

**3.** Enter **"security.dialog_enable_delay"** into the Filter text box.

**4.** Double click on that preference value and change the value to **0**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. I've done this once. Unfortunately right now I can't remember how.

**UPDATE:** Got it: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mr-tech-toolkit/developers

Just install this extension (and restart) and alongside with other features you'll get offered to remove the countdown next time you click to install an extension.

Comment: better :) lol :D

Comment: roland-taylor, the question was "can I...?". I've recieved "no, you cant" answers more than one time here, and some times even had to accept them as the corrct answers.

Comment: lol I just couldn't resist a laugh - that's all :D